# Wifi not working dell inspiron n4050

Tags: 12.04, wireless, router

The wireless connection of my laptop is not working. It keeps trying to connect but never connects. I read a lot of forums to solve the issue of my wireless connection but I did not succeed to make it work. Can somebody help me?

**Observation:** I was in the library at the university and the laptop connected smoothly to the eduroam wireless network and it didn't disconnect (so it was stable). At home I still have the problem described above. Windows connects wo problems at home... Does this give any hint to some expert?

**Possible workaround:** Finally I am thinking about upgrading the Ubuntu distro to 14.04.5 LTS this weekend. Also because there is no more support for 12.04 :(. To do so I will try the live CD and if everything works well I will run this command:

```
% sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I will let you know if this workaround solve the problem. It can be helpful for other people with the same issue =)

Comment: Which Os version you have?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: have you check system logs?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: Any output is displayed when executing "lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2"
@RGG: there is not logs because there is any error. It just keep trying to connect to different network but never connects